# Is it possible to import .gzip file into sqlite / Could I skip some column while importing?

Tags: sqlite, import, gzip

I tried to play around with .import but it seems to limited with csv and delimited file. Is it possible to import gzip file ? or at least, pipe from command line ?

Also, could I skip some un-wanted column like mysql "LOAD DATA INFILE" ?

Answer (score 16):

If you don't want to use named pipes, you could also:

```
zcat $YOURFILE.gz | sqlite3 $YOURDB.sqlite ".import /dev/stdin $TABLENAME"
```

If you need to modify stuff before import, you could use `perl` (or `awk`, `sed`, whatever) between the zcat and sqlite commands.

For example, if your file already uses the pipe character as a delimiter and you would like to import only columns 0 to 3 and 5 to 6:

```
zcat $YOURFILE.gz | perl -F'\|' -anle 'print join("|", @F[0..3,5..6])' | sqlite3 $YOURDB.sqlite ".import /dev/stdin $TABLENAME"
```

Comment: Unfortunately /dev/stdin isn't recognized on OSX so I had to resort to a named pipe

Answer (score 12):

```
$ mkfifo tempfile
$ zcat my_records.csv.gz > tempfile
```

This works like magic!

Although the `mkfifo` **does** create temporary file, the size of this file is 0 byte. 
When running this command `$ zcat my_records.csv.gz > tempfile`, it will halt at the command prompt. 
This allows you to run

```
sqlite3> .import tempfile db_table
```

After `sqlite3` finished importing the named pipe, `zcat` command will also finish running. You can then remove the named pipe.

```
$ rm -f tempfile
```

Comment: I was new to `mkfifo` when I found this answer and found these answers helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113986/example-of-using-named-pipes-in-linux-bash and http://askubuntu.com/questions/449132/why-use-a-named-pipe-instead-of-a-file

Answer (score 3):

```
zcat data.gz |\
  cat <(echo -e ".separator ','\n.import /dev/stdin dest_table") - |\
  sqlite3 db.sqlite
```

works nicely (linux).

Comment: Thanks nefuson! I couldn't get any of the other suggestion working for my use case (piping out of 7z-encrypted archive), but your brillant hack did it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a named pipe. It will act like a normal file but decompress on the fly. SQLite will know nothing about it.

It turns out the example on wikipedia is with gzip. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe

Comment: For some reason, I've always had problems with named pipes; if there's going to be a complicated file operation with a lot off seeking back and forth through it, it's prone to messing up.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a parser for data that would convert it to a series of SQL statements. Perl is a good language for that. It can even [handle gzip'd files](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/PerlIO-gzip/PerlIO/gzip.html).

Are you running this in a *Nix OS? If so, you could create a temporary file to hold the decompressed data:

```
tf="$(mktemp)" &&
zcat <my_records.csv.gz >"$tf"
sqlite3 /path/to/database.sqlite3 ".import $tf"
rm -f "$tf"
```

Comment: Well, I use ubuntu but I prefer "on the fly" instead of creating temporary file, since the data I working with is pretty huge when uncompressed.