# How to send more than one query string in Apache Bench?

Tags: apache, benchmarking, apachebench

ab -n 1 -c 1 http://localhost:2020/welTo.do?pxtId=3000007937&superDo=jack

I got answer for first query string but i also get

'superDo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Please help me

TIA

Regards
thiru

Answer (score 20):

You probably just need to quote the URL to avoid shell special characters from being interpreted. In this case your `&` symbol is causing the text to the left to be run in the background while attempting to run superDo as a command.

```
 ab -n 1 -c 1 'http://localhost:2020/welTo.do?pxtId=3000007937&superDo=jack'
```

Comment: Worked, but (at least on windows) I needed to use double-quotes (`"`)

Comment: If you get something like `apr_sockaddr_info_get() for localhost: no such host is known` then use IP `127.0.0.1` rather than `localhost`.

Answer (score 6):

There are two workarounds for this:

1. You can use double quote to surround the url:

> ab -n 1 -c 1 "http://localhost:2020/welTo.do?pxtId=3000007937&superDo=jack"

2. Escape "&" with a backslash:

> ab -n 1 -c 1 http://localhost:2020/welTo.do?pxtId=3000007937\&superDo=jack

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the post file? think this should work:

> ab -n 1 -c 1 -p postfile.txt -T 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' http://localhost:2020/welTo.do

And then make a flat file named postfile.txt with contents like this:

```
pxtId=3000007937&superDo=jack
```

Example adapted [from here](http://dfhu.org/blog/concurrent-php)

Comment: Hey is it possible to specify the post data within the command itself instead of the file just like in curl?

Comment: According to the docs this option isn't available, but you can create a named pipe and read from it, which is pretty much as storing the contents in a file. Any reason why you cant use a traditional file?

Comment: It's more convenient to specify the params in the command especially when they are few. And since curl and other tools do it, I expected ab to do the same. Otherwise am not exactly sure how to "create a named pipe and read from it".

Comment: @DavidOkwii This explains it pretty well http://stackoverflow.com/a/6675168/363217