# siege is ignoring query parameters

Tags: query-string, siege

I am testing siege against a simple server which outputs the n'th Fibonacci number. The server works great when using curl:

```
[mto@localhost ~]$ curl http://localhost:8000?q=8
21
```

Doing the same with siege, yields the following:

```
[mto@localhost ~]$ siege 'http://localhost:8000?q=8' -r 4 -c 1
** SIEGE 3.0.9
** Preparing 1 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege...
HTTP/1.1 400   0.00 secs:      73 bytes ==> GET  /
HTTP/1.1 400   0.00 secs:      73 bytes ==> GET  /
HTTP/1.1 400   0.00 secs:      73 bytes ==> GET  /
HTTP/1.1 400   0.00 secs:      73 bytes ==> GET  /
done.

Transactions:                  4 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:               1.01 secs
Data transferred:           0.00 MB
Response time:              0.00 secs
Transaction rate:           3.96 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:                0.00
Successful transactions:           0
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            0.00
Shortest transaction:           0.00

FILE: /home/mto/siege.log
You can disable this annoying message by editing
the .siegerc file in your home directory; change
the directive 'show-logfile' to false.
```

As you can see the server is giving 400. My webserver, written with tornado, outputs the following:

```
[W 150311 16:58:20 web:1404] 400 GET / (127.0.0.1): Missing argument q
[W 150311 16:58:20 web:1811] 400 GET / (127.0.0.1) 0.85ms             
[W 150311 16:58:20 web:1404] 400 GET / (127.0.0.1): Missing argument q
[W 150311 16:58:20 web:1811] 400 GET / (127.0.0.1) 0.71ms             
[W 150311 16:58:20 web:1404] 400 GET / (127.0.0.1): Missing argument q
[W 150311 16:58:20 web:1811] 400 GET / (127.0.0.1) 0.72ms             
[W 150311 16:58:20 web:1404] 400 GET / (127.0.0.1): Missing argument q
[W 150311 16:58:20 web:1811] 400 GET / (127.0.0.1) 0.79ms
```

How do I pass the query parameters to siege? The Siege man page says the following:

```
   ...
   You can pass parameters using GET much like you would in a web browser:

   www.haha.com/form.jsp?first=homer&last=simpson

   If you invoke the URL as a command line argument, you should probably place it in
   quotes.
   ...
```

I have tried to put the url in single, double and no quotes. I have also written the urls in a file and passed it to siege using `-f`, but no luck. I am using:

My environment:

```
SIEGE 3.0.9
GNOME Terminal 3.10.2
Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am using SIEGE 4.0.4 and found that double quotes works from the answer of below question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9311812/5824101

Answer (score 0):

siege does not like the url to be at the following form:

```
http://localhost:8000?q=8
```

To use query parameters I have to have a url with a path:

```
http://localhost:8000/fib?q=8
```

Then it works fine. I have not been able to find a work around