# Can I take an output stream, duplicate it with tee, munge one of them, and pipe BOTH back as input into diff?

Tags: shell, unix, io, pipe, tee

As an example, taking one single program's stdout, obtaining two copies of it with `tee` and sending them both (one or preferably both able to be piped through other programs) back into `vimdiff`.

Bonus points if it can be done without having to create a file on disk.

I know how to direct input into a program that takes two inputs, like this

```
vimdiff <(curl http://google.com) <(curl http://archives.com/last_night/google.com)
```

and with tee for making two output streams

```
echo "abc" | tee >(sed 's/a/zzz/') >(sed 's/c/zzz/')
```

but I do not know how to connect the pipes back together into a diamond shape.

Comment: check out the mkfifo command, it is meant to do what I think you decribe.

Comment: That's fantastic! It's cool to finally find a use for something that I vaguely knew about but never used. Thanks.

Comment: @NSD Well the question came out of a curiosity. But to use FIFOs to achieve my original task would be a little silly. I was working with files so I just referenced those files. I was simply thinking about "well what if I only had a stream and it was not already saved in a file".

Comment: Someone should write an answer, maybe give a short example of how to make and use fifos with `mkfifo` in one-liners. I'd accept the crap out of that.

Comment: @StevenLu Thanks , now i understand the scenario .... actually i got a bit confused first when i read "I do not know how to connect the pipes back together into a diamond shape" in the question .... as per my concept pipes are used in a single directon ie provide the output of one command as input to the command following after , and your question gave me a idea of reversing everything the other way !! ....

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113986/example-of-using-named-pipes-in-linux-bash

Comment: @NSD My diamond shape thing still makes sense. The T (tee) which is the upper half of the diamond can still be there. One side of it can be directly piped to the two-stream-receiver (the bottom half of the diamond) while the remaining two ends are attached to a FIFO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so hard if you can use a fifo:

```
test -e fifo || mkfifo fifo
echo abc | tee >(sed s/a/zzz/ > fifo) | sed s/c/zzz/ | diff - fifo
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as a side note, to have this work under ZSH an extra ">" is needed after tee (multios option should be set):

```
$ setopt multios
$ test -e fifo || mkfifo fifo
$ echo abc | tee > >(sed s/a/zzz/ > fifo) | sed s/c/zzz/ | diff - fifo
```