# Is there any way to select some of values for SUMO to write to the output file

Tags: file-io, sumo

I would like to generate the FullOutput file in SUMO, but in https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Output/FullOutput.html we can see that, FullOutput file seems like that:

```
<full-export>
    <data timestep="<TIME_STEP>">

    <vehicles>
        <vehicle id="<VEHICLE_ID>" eclass="<VEHICLE_ECLASS>" co2="<VEHICLE_CO2>" co="<VEHICLE_CO>" hc="<VEHICLE_HC>"
        nox="<VEHICLE_NOX>" pmx="<VEHICLE_PMX>" fuel="<VEHICLE_FUEL>" electricity="<VEHICLE_ELECTRICITY>" noise="<VEHICLE_NOISE>" route="<VEHICLE_ROUTE>" type="<VEHICLE_TYPE>"
        waiting="<VEHICLE_WAITING>" lane="<VEHICLE_LANE>" pos_lane="<VEHICLE_POS_LANE>" speed="<VEHICLE_SPEED>"
        angle="<VEHICLE_ANGLE>" x="<VEHICLE_POS_X>" y="<VEHICLE_POS_Y>"/>

        ... more vehicles ...

    </vehicles>

    <edges>

        <edge id="<EDGE_ID>" traveltime="<EDGE_TRAVELTIME>">

        <lane id="<LANE_ID>" co="<LANE_CO>" co2="<LANE_CO2>" nox="<LANE_NOX>" pmx="<LANE_CO>"
        hc="<LANE_HC>" noise="<LANE_NOISE>" fuel="<LANE_FUEL>" electricity="<LANE_ELECTRICITY>" maxspeed="<LANE_MAXSPEED>" meanspeed="<LANE_MEANSPEED>"
        occupancy="<LANE_OCCUPANCY>" vehicle_count="<LANE_VEHICLES_COUNT>"/>

            ... more lanes of the edge if exists

        </edge>

            ... more edges of the network

    </edges>

    <tls>
        <trafficlight id="0/0" state="GgGr"/>
        ... more traffic lights

    </tls>

</data>

... the next timestep ...

</full-export>
```

The outputed .xml file is too big, usually more than 1GB, and it contains a lot of values, such as

```
eclass="<VEHICLE_ECLASS>" co2="<VEHICLE_CO2>" co="<VEHICLE_CO>" hc="<VEHICLE_HC>"
        nox="<VEHICLE_NOX>" pmx="<VEHICLE_PMX>" fuel="<VEHICLE_FUEL>"
```

which I don't need.

So I wonder, is there any way to select some of values I need to output?

Answer (score 0):

You have different options here:

1. Use a different output. Maybe fcd-output is already enough. It contains all the vehicle positions and you can usually aggregate it yourself to edges if you want to. Furthermore fcd-output can also be given a list of attributes to write using `--fcd-output.attributes` (full-output does not have this feature).
2. Filter the output directly. Instead of giving an output file you can give a socket connection and sumo will direct the output there. See https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/blob/main/tests/complex/sumo/socketout/runner.py for an example.
3. If you are on Linux use a named pipe [Example of using named pipes in Linux shell (Bash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113986/example-of-using-named-pipes-in-linux-shell-bash) and filter yourself
4. Redirect the output to the [xml2csv.py](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Tools/Xml.html) script which removes at least the XML overhead and it may be easier to remove columns in a csv files depending on your setup.